# Squid reverse-proxy for site on Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, reverse-proxy, squid

I'm setting up a squid 3.1 reverse proxy server (accelerator) for my website on Google AppEngine. The squid.conf looks like this,

```
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=my.public.domain.name ignore-cc
cache_peer mysite.appspot.com parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS name=gaeAccel
acl gae dstdomain my.public.domain.name
http_access allow gae
http_access deny all
cache_peer_access gaeAccel allow gae
cache_peer_access gaeAccel deny all
```

Squid redirects me to the Google's search home page.

As soon as I changed `mysite.appspot.com` in `cache_peer` to anything else, such as `www.yahoo.com`, it worked.

Any idea?

It's on Ubuntu Server 12.04, Squid 3.1.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to bypass GFW, use [Cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Using your own proxy server makes it a single point of failure, effectively defeating one of main purposes of GAE - reliability.

App Engine already has their own transparent caching servers:

1. For static content you can set this explicitly via [`expiration` attribute](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Setting_the_Browser_Cache_Expiration).
2. For dynamic content you can set `Cache-Control` http header, which Google transparent cache will then honor: http://davepeck.org/2011/10/25/a-word-on-app-engine-caching/

Note: you still pay for the bandwidth at $0.12/Gb. But OTOH, you proxy and it's traffic are free neither.

Comment: The reverse-proxy server is not only for caching, but for by-passing Great Firewall of China. Direct access to a site on GAE is blocked there.